# Javascript - Error Initializing Cloud Firestore through Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm migrating a simple html / javascript project from firebase realtime database to cloud firestore. I've followed the [quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and added the library for firebase-firestore - but when I try to initialise the firestore I get *'Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function'*.  The quickstart mentions:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");
```

.. but I think that's only if I'm using npn to get the libraries, and doesn't apply?

What am I missing?

index.html

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

app.js

```
(function()

  {var config = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
  };

 firebase.initializeApp(config);

 var oldDB = firebase.database(); <-- THIS WORKS
 // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
 var newDB = firebase.firestore(); <-- 'Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function'
```

Answer (score 0):

The firestore sdk isn't included it the main firebase package. You need to import both:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
```

and

```
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the problem was my error - calling the js from another html without the reference to the firebase-firestore library added.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I was calling the javascript from another html page, where I hadn't updated the library references to include the one for firebase-firestore. When this was updated the firestore db initialisation worked fine..